# How do KLT and SVD differ from each other?

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals

What are the differences between KLT and SVD? It looks more or less similar to me. Did I misunderstand the concepts? Explain me more about SVD and if possible provide me the link for SVD (Image Processing). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From the direct implementations of the two, SVD and KLT are different since $S$ in SVD is a diagonal matrix, while $C$ in KLT is not. Besides, KLT is originally used to describe a stationary process. In its expansion, an infinite number of basis functions is required to
form a complete set. Yet for a random vector $X$, it can be rephreased in terms of a linear combination of orthonornal basis vectors, then covariance matrix $C$ is furtherly derived.

For a 2D image, we can view it as $M$ realizations of stochastic process $x$ where $M$ is the row of the image. And the assumption is that all rows have the same row covariance matrix $C$, then the KLT can be somehow converted to the form of SVD. In other words, when considering a multivariate stochastic process, the SVD and the KLT are computationally equivalent. That's why in most cases people view the both as the same. For mathematical details, refer to [The KL transform and eigenimages](http://saig.physics.ualberta.ca/s/sites/default/files/chapter6.pdf).

In the application of image compression, the global KLT is used for the whole image, while SVD is better applied to each block. In [Patrick et al's Hybrid KLT-SVD Image Compression](http://mirlab.org/conference_papers/International_Conference/ICASSP%201997/pdf/scan/ic972713.pdf), they combined the two method to implement the adaptive transform on the blocks to achieve a better coding efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

KLT and SVD are essentially the same, except KLT is applied to continuous linear operators, and SVD is applied to finite-variable linear operators (matrices).

The principal idea is the same: given a linear function (or operator), we find a basis representation for the inputs in such a way that every component of this basis would get multiplied by a number. This is more simply knows as eigenvalue decomposition.

Comment: Thank you.. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: On which part exactly?

Comment: In terms for image processing.. In my syllabus (Advanced Digital Image Processing), I have both KLT and SVD. Why we need to study both? Image is a finite-variable linear operator right? I am unsure about the terms   continuous linear operators and finite-variable linear operators (matrices). Do you mean Continuous Signal and Discrete Signal ?